# Only 10 app pools per web server?

Tags: 2013, topology, application-pool, front-end

I'm reading the [software limits for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx), and find that only 10 app pools per web server is supported. It's a threshold limit type, meaning I can exceed it, but probably I would lose in performance.

What are my options to isolate service application pools from web application pools? Do I really need a second web server to use more than 10 app pools? Or should I organize service application pools in an application server (not serving as a second web server)?

I'm confused.

Comment: Isn't the regular setup usually an application server for service applications and then a WFE server for web applications?

Comment: @DanielZiga, it truly is. Funny thing to think about though is how this threshold works on a Single-Server installation, where this limit is already exceeded at start ;)

Comment: What is the need to isolate Service/Web App Pools?  And the model has shifted with 2013, where 'low latency' Service Applications run on the 'WFE' (or the server the users interact with), higher latency SAs run on batch processing (e.g. App) servers.

Comment: Nice! Is there a recommendation on which service apps that are low/high latency? My guess would be that Search, User Profile and Managed Metadata (if used for navigation) are high latency...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [Topologies for SharePoint 2013 (streamlined ones)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp123594.aspx), you find that the least fault tolerant setup is two servers, combined front ends and application servers (batch processing servers), and a database server.

I've seen this setup on 2010 solutions, and it's quite limited when working with 7000 users. But this gives advantage over 1 WFE and 1 app server and 1 db-server which isn't fault tolerant at all. Any server outage and your SharePoint environment is either out of business, or suffering severely (if app server is down).

Advice here is to use two servers combined as WFE and app server.